# 'unknown type name' error while using Cython to generate C code

Tags: python, c, cython, code-translation

I have successfully generated .c file using Cython, but when i try to compile it using gcc, i get these errors... This is just the first line of the error... There are 3 pages of errors similar to this... My .py code is a simple:

```
print "test"
```

error:

```
unknown type name ‘Py_UNICODE’
static CYTHON_INLINE size_t __Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen(const Py_UNICODE *u)
```

Comment: PyPy is a JIT. It does not generate C code. What makes you think PyPy can do this for you?

Comment: I have been experimenting with cython and pypy, and it seems i have mistaken pypy for cython...

Comment: OK, edited your question accordingly!

Comment: Modifying the question this extensively does no one any favors. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You have *alot* of SO reputation. Do you think this is a case for a rollback?

Comment: @user1176999 See my updated answer below for a link describing Cython compilation and compiler flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/XvCV-TKKnEw).

Citing it:

```
Cython is not a Python to C compiler in the sense that it does away
with the Python interpreter/runtime, rather it creates .c files that
are compiled against the Python/C API and can be loaded into a running
session.
```

See [this list of interpreters](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations#Compilers) which lists some compilers that might be useful to you!

For a guide to compilation, also have a look at [the compilation page of the Cython wiki](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html)

Comment: Sure, but why can't it leave the intermediate .c file regardless?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is indeed possible to compile to C, once you get a `.pyx` file, see http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html